# changing SQL server table entries into uppercase(input by vb.net in c#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I am using sql server for database and visual studio for inserting data in a table but i want the entered entries to be changed into uppercase before entry in database. which syntax to use for that.
Tell me what changes I can make in this statement:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into student values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')", con);
```

Comment: `ToUpper()` on the `Text` should work for you and also please use parameters (search on for SQL injection, you need to know about it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.ToUpper();`
some thing like this

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
"insert into student values('" + 
 TextBox1.Text.ToUpper() + "','" + 
 TextBox2.Text.ToUpper() + "','" + 
 TextBox3.Text.ToUpper() + "')",
 con);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Google for SQL Injection, and change this to a parametrized query
2. Either TextBox.Text.ToUpper method:

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@Param1", TextBox1.Text.ToUpper()
INSERT INTO ... VALUES(@Param1, @Param2,...)
```

or use the SQL UPPER function (SQL Server) - it's UCASE in some other databases:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES( UPPER(@Param1), UPPER(@Param2),...)
```

If you care about internationalization, be aware that `ToUpper()` without parameters will use the current culture (`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`) to decide how to convert to upper case.  SQL Server's UPPER function will depend on the database collation, so might give a different result.  Google for "Turkish I problem" to understand the kind of issues this might cause.

Comment: I assume you mean [`UPPER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
"insert into student 
values('" + TextBox1.Text.ToUpper() + "','" 
          + TextBox2.Text.ToUpper() + "','" 
          + TextBox3.Text.ToUpper() + "')", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is c#

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into student values('" + TextBox1.Text.ToUpper() + "','" + TextBox2.Text.ToUpper() + "','" + TextBox3.Text.ToUpper() + "')", con); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Check for sql injection, and use SqlParameters though.